# AudioKit handling of AVAudioSessionInterruption

Tags: ios, iphone, avaudiosession, audiokit, interruption

After receiving a phone call or just having the phone ring our background play enabled AudioKit app goes silent for good and I am not sure how to handle that. The only way to restart sound output is to kill and restart the app. Other interruptions like enabling and using Siri work without a hitch and the app's sound is ducked during the event.

Typically an app can register itself to receive notifications (e.g. `NSNotification.Name.AVAudioSessionInterruption`) to detect an `AVAudioSession` interruption, but how does one retrieve the `AVSession` object that is normally passed into the notification?

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(AppDelegate.sessionInterrupted(_:)),
                                               name: NSNotification.Name.AVAudioSessionInterruption,
                                               object: MISSING_AK_AVAUDIOSESSION_REF)
```

Furthermore, if one were able to successfully implement audio interrupt notifications, what happens with AudioKit? It is not designed to be "restarted" or put on hold. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This is going to depend on your app how you handle this. At very least, you'll want to do Audiokit.stop() and then Audiokit.start() when the interruption is finished.

You'll want to register for the notification with something like this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(handleInterruption),
                                           name: .AVAudioSessionInterruption,
                                           object: nil)
```

Then handle it with something like this:

```
@objc internal func handleInterruption(_ notification: Notification) {
    guard let info = notification.userInfo,
        let typeValue = info[AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] as? UInt,
        let type = AVAudioSessionInterruptionType(rawValue: typeValue) else {
            return
    }
    //...handle each type here
}
```